# How can I detect if an object is complete in a image?

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, detectron

I'm using **Detectron2** for object detection and I'm looking for a way to understand that if the detected object from Detectron2 is the full object or is the part of it. For example, I'm interested in detecting cars and I want to know if the detected car has appeared fully or partially.

[Full car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVa06.png): the car detected must be seen in a complete way.

[Partial car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GympO.jpg): a part of the car detected is not visible.

My approach is when I detect an object of the **car** class, I check the location of the box and if it's close to the edge I classify it as **partial**, otherwise **full** but in some cases this approach doesn't work.  Is there any way to show only the bounding box when the car detected completely, not part of the car?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you're right, it's done